# Are the any Guidelines to Create Inputmasks in Javascript-

Tags: javascript

I want to create different inputmasks like Date Input mask in Javascript.
What will be the best way to create masks. **(Without any Framework!)**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an event listener to the onKeyDown handler on your input. Something like this:

```
function numericOnly( e )
{

if( !e ) e = event;
var kc = e.which || e.keyCode;
var shift = e.shiftKey;

// Numeric and decimal point only
return( kc == 8 || kc == 9 || kc == 46 ||     // Backspace, tab, delete
        kc == 37 || kc == 39 ||               // Left and right arrow keys
        kc == 110 || kc == 190 ||             // Decimal point (keyboard and num pad)
      ( kc >= 48 && kc <= 57 && !shift ) ||   // Digits above letter (no shift)
      ( kc >= 96 && kc <= 105 ) );            // Digits on num pad
}
```

For date validation you would also include the / character. Then I would attach an event handler to the onBlur event on your inputs. Use that even handler to run the input against a regex to make sure a proper date was entered.

```
<input onkeydown="JavaScript: numericOnly( e );"
       onblur="JavaScript: checkDate( this.value );">
```